# How to change this shader to solid color?

Tags: visual-c++, directx-11, hlsl, pixel-shader

I tried changing "float4 Color: COLOR1" but didn't help because it's for Diffuse or specular color. I don't know what else to do, I don't know what to add.

I ran out of ideas.

```
HRESULT GenerateShader(ID3D11Device* pD3DDevice, ID3D11PixelShader**pShader, float r, float g, float b)
{
char szCast[] = "struct VS_OUT"
    "{"
    " float4 Position : SV_Position;"
    " float4 Color : COLOR0;"
    "};"

    "float4 main( VS_OUT input ) : SV_Target"
    "{"
    " float4 fake;"
    " fake.a = 0.5f;"
    " fake.r = %0.2f;"
    " fake.g = %0.2f;"
    " fake.b = %0.2f;"
    " return fake;"
    "}";
ID3D10Blob* pBlob;
char szPixelShader[1000];

sprintf(szPixelShader, szCast, r, g, b);

ID3DBlob* d3dErrorMsgBlob;

HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(szPixelShader, sizeof(szPixelShader), "shader", NULL, NULL, "main", "ps_4_0", NULL, NULL, &pBlob, &d3dErrorMsgBlob);

if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

hr = pD3DDevice->CreatePixelShader((DWORD*)pBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, pShader);

if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have taken the code from here: [GenerateShader for DirectX11](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/d3d-tutorials-source/75474-generateshader-directx11.html)

The point of having the "%" sign in the original code:

```
fake.r = %f;
fake.g = %f;
fake.b = %f;
```

is to edit the shader later on with *sprintf* and parameters *r,g,b*.

```
sprintf(szPixelShader, szCast, r, g, b);
```

So writing *%0.2f* does not make sense. If you want hardcoded color values, try removing the "%" signs in your code, so it would be as below:

```
fake.r = 0.2f;
fake.g = 0.2f;
fake.b = 0.2f;
```

Where the call to *sprintf* would be unnecessary (and would create an error since the target string has no parameters to print the rgb values to).

For more info on [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).